# how to return login partial view from accountcontroller to modal view in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

in my case I have partial login view and I try to open in modal. That is works fine but accountcontroller return partialview inside the account controller like account/_login, I expected the open in modal. I'm sharing my code. Thanks for giving a time.

_Layout.cshtml

```
...
@*Sign up*@
<div id="modal-signup" class="modal-signup-box modal-box">
      @Html.Partial("_Signup")
</div>
@*Login*@
<div id="modal-login" class="modal-login-box modal-box">
      @Html.Partial("_Login")
</div>
...
```

_Login.cshtml (Partial)

```
@using UcuzaBE.WebApp.Models
@model LoginViewModel

<section>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("_Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
            <i class="fa fa-user input-icon input-icon-show"></i>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control input-text full-width", @placeholder = "e-mail" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
            <i class="fa fa-lock input-icon input-icon-show"></i>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control input-text full-width", @placeholder = "pass" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }


</section>

<div class="seperator"></div>
<p><a href="#modal-signup" class="goto-signup my-popupbox">Signup</a></p>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

custom.js

```
// login box
$("body").on("click", ".modal-signup-box .signup-email", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".modal-signup-box").find(".simple-signup").hide();
    $(this).closest(".modal-signup-box").find(".email-signup").show();
    $(this).closest(".modal-signup-box").find(".email-signup").find(".input-text").eq(0).focus();
});

$("body").on("click", ".my-popupbox", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sourceId = $(this).attr("href");
    if (typeof sourceId == "undefined") {
        sourceId = $(this).data("target");
    }
    if (typeof sourceId == "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    if ($(sourceId).length < 1) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).fPopup({
        wrapId: "my-popupbox",
    });
});
```

And also AccountController.cs is

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> _Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView("_Login", model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "error message.");
                return PartialView("_Login",model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Create a homepage view which will load First then on that View render both , Login and signup partial view which will be displayed in Modal pop.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I already have a homepage also Login and Signup partial pages showing in modal but when I send form to the accountcontroller the page not comes in modal, it opens in a http://.../Account/_Login